# Apple Script Error: Can't continue click

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I'm trying to open a messaging application (it does not have an Apple Script Dictionary (command + shift + o)), click on text, and type into the text box, and hit send.

> Pop up: Script Error - `Telegram got an error: Can't continue click` after the application becomes active.
>
> Result Tab: `error "Telegram got an error: Can’t continue click." number -1708`

*P.S., The messaging application is Telegram*.

> Apple Script:

```
tell application "Telegram"
    activate
    delay 1
    click on text "chat name"
    keystroke "some text"     
    //assuming this works because text box is the first responder when the chat opens.
    click on text "Send"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an application lacks an AppleScript dictionary, any command except the standard commands `launch`, `activate`, `open`, `reopen` and `quit` will throw an error.

The solution is GUI scripting: The built-in application `System Events` is the bridge to send mouse clicks and keyboard events to the target application.

I don't know the application Telegram at all, so this code might fail, but it might also be a starting point

```
activate application "Telegram"
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Telegram"
    tell window 1
      keystroke "some text"     
      click button "Send"
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Is there a way I can replicate `click on text "chat name"`?

Comment: try `set value of text field 1 to "some text"`. if there are more text fields the index might be different

Comment: No, by chat name I mean selecting a chat and then select the text field to type in. Like - `activate` -> select `chat name` -> select `text field` -> type `some text` -> hit `send` button.

Comment: it's probably possible, but GUI scripting depends strongly on the UI environment. Try UIElementInspector to find out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices for a 3rd party app that lacks an AppleScript dictionary.

Option 1:

Use System Events as described above to perform an action on an element, e.g. click a button, keystroke text into a field, etc.  The trick is to identify the element in syntax that is recognized by Applescript.  Besides UIElementInspector mentioned above, which can be confusing and occasionally wrong/incomplete, you can also run the following commands in a separate Applescript Editor.  For example, to get all UI elements for the active window (window 1) in Telegram:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Telegram" to tell window 1
            UI elements
    end tell
```

To get all UI elements for the main menu bar in Telegram:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Telegram" to tell menu bar 1
            UI elements
    end tell
```

In each case the Result pane will display a comma delimited list of all available UI elements in that window or menu bar.  Moreover, the syntax as listed is guaranteed to be recognizable by Applescript.  Just identify the correct element and tell System Events to tell it what to do.

For example if you want to click the Menu item "Format" In TextEdit first run the following:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "TextEdit" to tell menu bar 1
        UI elements
    end tell
```

Among the results in the Result pane will be the following:

```
     menu bar item "Format" of menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit" of application "System Events"
```

Convert that to Applescript, run the script and it will click the "Format" Menu:

```
    tell application "TextEdit" to activate --you need TexEdit up and running to click its menu bar

    tell application "System Events" to click menu bar item "Format" of menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit"
```

For submenus, etc. you just iterate the process asking for UI elements for the submenu.  GUI scripting is iterative and empirical.

Option 2:

Download the free Terminal/Command Line app [cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) which allows you to click on any point in the screen. The screen coordinates you want to click can be manually identified with your cursor by holding down command + shift + 4.